# jquery-ajax doesn't give back the response. It is still loading and loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, onload

I am doing 5 to 6 Ajax calls on page onload, but some of them are not giving back their response.

On Stack Overflow, I find to put `async:false` (what will happen when I will do this? **Will it solve my problem?**), and I also find that it is not recommended to use `async:false` (why is it not recommended?)

What do I have to do?

Comment: it'll make your page freeze, until you get a response from the server.

Comment: The issue with the AJAX calls might be something in your code, or it might be the server itself. Make sure you're structuring your AJAX request properly. And no, using `async` is not likely to solve anything.

Comment: you should check the network tab on your browser's inspector, the call should return something (at least an error on timeout), if you have a server error you should check the server logs. I would try to debug one call at a time, try all of them separated, don't user async:false

Answer (score 0):

If you set async to false it's no longer an Ajax call. It's instead a regular blocking synchronous call to the web server.

It's unclear what type of issue you're having with your Ajax calls, but a common error is some sort of timing-related error. Remember that it's not deterministic which order the Ajax requests will complete in. The second request might complete before the first request and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and `then` functions of jQuery:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/request1.php" ), $.ajax( "/request2.php" ) )
.then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

It shows when the first two requests will complete, and then you can call a function to send more Ajax requests.